# Does the 3.8% tax surcharge include income below $200,000?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investment-income

For a single taxpayer, I have read that there is a 3.8% surcharge on investment income if the person makes more than $200,000 from all sources. Does that even include the income below $200,000?

For example, let's say I have $50,000 in ordinary income and $149,000 in long term capital gains, then I pay no surcharge. But if I have $151,000 in long term capital gains, then I would pay 3.8% of the entire $151,000? Is that how it works?

Comment: Just FYI, the US tax code almost always prevents the concern you address, which is sometimes called a "tax cliff". There are some exceptions, but they are rare.

Answer (score 5):

From [Medicare taxes and you](https://www.fidelity.com/viewpoints/personal-finance/new-medicare-taxes)

> The amount you owe is based on the lesser of your total net investment
>   income or the amount of your MAGI that exceeds $200,000 for
>   individuals, $250,000 for couples filing jointly, or $125,000 for
>   spouses filing separately.
>
> In other words, you owe the 3.8% tax on the amount by which your
>   investment income exceeds the income thresholds, or, if your wages
>   alone already are higher than the income thresholds, you'll owe tax on
>   the lesser of net investment income or MAGI that exceeds the
>   thresholds.